# Rewrite value of array in file

Tags: php, arrays, file, url-rewriting

> **data.php**

```
<?php
return [
            "L1" => array('Vanessa', 'Prague', 'OK'),
            "L2" => array('Alex', 'Paris', 'OK'),
            "L3" => array('Paul', 'Paris', 'OK'),
            "L4" => array('John', 'Madrid', 'OK')
];
```

> **index.php**

```
<?php
   $data = include('data.php');
   $people = array($data); 

// Show data
   echo "<table><tr><td>Name</td><td>City</td><td>Confirm</td></tr>";

   foreach ($data as $vypis) {

      echo "  
            <tr>
                <td>$vypis[0]</td>
                <td>$vypis[1]</td>
                <td>$vypis[2]</td>
                <td>$vypis[3]</td>
            </tr>
      ";   
   }

   echo "</table>";

?>
```

How can I rewrite *"OK"* in **L3** like this:

```
            "L3" => array('Paul', 'Paris', 'REWRITE'),
```

I tried use **str_replace**, but I don´t know how to locate L3 OK value.

```
$path_to_file = 'data.php';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$file_contents = str_replace( ??? ,'REWRITE',$file_contents);
```

Some tip how to **locate [3] in L3 and rewrite** it?

Ofcourse itsn´t optimal solution, I am amateur. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a native php function array_map:

```
$data = include('data.php');

$data['L3'] = array_map('replaceOk', $data['L3']);

//callback for array_map function
function replaceOk ($item) {
    return $item === 'OK' ? 'REWRITE' : $item;
}
```

However if you are sure that these arrays always have 3 elements, you can do it in that way:

```
$data['L3'][2] = 'REWRITE';
```

**UPDATE**

According to your requirements I've created the following solution:

```
$path_to_file = 'data.php';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$startPos = strpos($file_contents, 'L3');
$subStr = substr($file_contents, $startPos);
$subStrUpdated = preg_replace('/(OK)/', 'REWRITE', $subStr, 1);
$file_contents = str_replace($subStr, $subStrUpdated, $file_contents);
file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
```

It finds a position of 'L3' in the string, then cuts string into two substrings. After that it replaces 'OK' in second substring but only once. Then it replaces original substring in file's content on the updated one. All hardcoded values such as 'L3', 'OK' or 'REWRITE' could be replaced on more real values, or it could be wrapped in function with arguments - it is up to you.

**UPDATE2**

I've slightly updated the code to prevent replacing the substring after L4:

```
$path_to_file = 'data.php';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$startPos = strpos($file_contents, 'L3');
$length = strpos($file_contents, 'L4') - $startPos;
$subStr = substr($file_contents, $startPos, $length);
$subStrUpdated = preg_replace('/(OK)/', 'REWRITE', $subStr);
$file_contents = str_replace($subStr, $subStrUpdated, $file_contents);
file_put_contents($path_to_file, $file_contents);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need change only one OK in L3.

Comment: Nice job! And how can I rewrite it in data.php? Is possible change 'OK' by key? (Sometimes will not be only "OK")

Comment: 1. If you want to change content of file, you will need to open it, update and then close. I don't understand why you need it when you can write a programme that would retrieve a content of the file and then process retrieved data. Like $data = include('data.php'); 2. If you always will need to update the third element, then yes you can access it by key: $data['L3'][2]

Comment: In EDIT you can see what I need, but its not working.

Comment: Excuse me, I completely do not understand your goals. Anyway, code that you added is working - it replaces 'OK' in the file. Second, after updating file you can again retrieve that array from there. BUT Why do you need to write it to file? Can you save updated array to the variable and then use if for array_sum?

Comment: Code in edit is not work well, it change all data in [2] column, I need only ['L3'][2], what I must change? I dont know how clearly explain problem with array_sum, thats for create another question, but saved data solve it.

Comment: @MartinTůma I've update the answer according to your requirements. I very hope that is exactly what you asked for

Comment: @MartinTůma does posted solution meet your requirements?

Comment: I'm so sorry for the late reply. Yeah thats it! 
It solves my problem. I have one last question. Is possible change code to stop rewriting, when didn´t find OK in L3? Because in this case it starts rewriting L4.

Comment: Could you provide details? I've tested that code on my local machine and everything works as you asked for

Comment: Oh sorry, my fault. All is OK, thank you very much for your time!